# Rails 3 Resource: Share Custom Actions with Nested Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 2 resources `events` and `patients`

```
resources :events do
  collection do
    get :upcoming
    get :missed
  end
end

resources :patients do
  resources :events # does not have upcoming or missed
end
```

Is there a way to have the `events` nested resource within the `patients` definition share the custom collection members from the primary events resource without having to define them again?

Comment: Good question, I as well have been trying to get the above to work but with no success. The rails 3 guide does not go into the details of nested custom routes. If anyone has come across a solution to this please include the link here.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method in your routes file and can call it each time, as such keep DRY.

```
def events_actions
  collection do
    get :upcoming
    get :missed
  end
end

resources :events do
  events_actions
end

resources :patients do
  resources :events do
    events_actions
  end
end
```

Or take things even further:

```
def resources_events
  resources :events do      
    collection do
      get :upcoming
      get :missed
    end
  end
end

resources_events

resources :patients do
  resources_events
end
```